Unable to use producerTemplate when application is gracefully shutting down
I have a spring-boot application which uses apache camel where i have graceful shutdown enabled for both spring and apache camel.
Following are the graceful setting that i have applied.
Spring-boot config
Spring:
  lifecycle:
    timeout-per-shutdown-phase: 9m

server:
  shutdown: graceful

Camel Config
@Configuration
public class CamelConfig {

    @Bean
    public CamelContextConfiguration contextConfiguration() {
        return new CamelContextConfiguration() {
            @Override
            public void beforeApplicationStart(CamelContext context) {
                DefaultShutdownStrategy shutdownStrategy = new DefaultShutdownStrategy(context);
                shutdownStrategy.setTimeout(420);
                shutdownStrategy.setShutdownNowOnTimeout(true);
                shutdownStrategy.setShutdownRoutesInReverseOrder(true);
                context.setShutdownStrategy(shutdownStrategy);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterApplicationStart(CamelContext camelContext) {
            }
    };
    }
}

I using following line of code to put message on kafka when my spring application is shutting down.
Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
headers.put("url", "kafka:wfm_tenant-ack-q-dev?retries=0&maxBlockMs=2000&synchronous=true&shutdownTimeout=420000&requestTimeoutMs=2000&key=f4077a38-a6ae-4ad4-b959-24a6923");
producerTemplate.requestBodyAndHeaders(DIRECT_ENDPOINT,jacksonJsonMapperService.getJsonString(body),headers);

The route is as following
from(DIRECT_ENDPOINT)
                .routeId(DIRECT_ENDPOINT)
                .doTry()
                .toD("${header.url}")
                .doCatch(Exception.class)
                .to(OPERATION_RESPONSE_PROCESSOR_EXCEPTION_HANDLER)
                .end();

I am getting following exception when code tries to invoke requestBodyAndHeaders of producerTemplate

2024-10-30 14:18:42.138 ERROR 20746 --- \[icecode1-q-dev\]\] c.d.b.w.r.r.RequestExceptionRoutes       : traceId: 54ADECDC60627FC-0000000000000001 exception in response processor:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer.send(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord)" because "this.kafkaProducer" is null
at org.apache.camel.component.kafka.KafkaProducer.processSingleMessageSync(KafkaProducer.java:392) \~\[camel-kafka-3.17.0.jar:3.17.0\]
at org.apache.camel.component.kafka.KafkaProducer.process(KafkaProducer.java:385) \~\[camel-kafka-3.17.0.jar:3.17.0\]
at org.apache.camel.support.SynchronousDelegateProducer.process(SynchronousDelegateProducer.java:48) \~\[camel-support-3.17.0.jar:3.17.0\]
at org.apache.camel.support.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:66) \~\[camel-support-3.17.0.jar:3.17.0\]
at org.apache.camel.processor.SendDynamicProcessor.lambda$process$0(SendDynamicProcessor.java:197) \~\[camel-core-processor-3.17.0.jar:3.17.0\]
at org.apache.camel.support.cache.DefaultProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(DefaultProducerCache.java:327) \~\[camel-support-3.17.0.jar:3.17.0\]
at org.apache.camel.processor.SendDynamicProcessor.process(SendDynamicProcessor.java:182) \~\[camel-core-processor-3.17.0.jar:3.17.0\]
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:399) \~\[camel-base-engine-3.17.0.jar:3.17.0\]
at org.apache.camel.processor.TryProcessor$TryState.run(TryProcessor.java:109) \~\[camel-core-processor-3.17.0.jar:3.17.0\]
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.executeFromQueue(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:220) \~\[camel-base-engine-3.17.0.jar:3.17.0\]
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.executeFromQueue(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:79) \~\[camel-base-engine-3.17.0.jar:3.17.0\]
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.await(DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.java:96) \~\[camel-base-engine-3.17.0.jar:3.17.0\]
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.process(DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.java:85) \~\[camel-base-engine-3.17.0.jar:3.17.0\]
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.SharedCamelInternalProcessor.process(SharedCamelInternalProcessor.java:108) \~\[camel-base-engine-3.17.0.jar:3.17.0\]
at org.apache.camel.support.cache.DefaultProducerCache.send(DefaultProducerCache.java:199) \~\[camel-support-3.17.0.jar:3.17.0\]
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:176) \~\[camel-base-engine-3.17.0.jar:3.17.0\]
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:172) \~\[camel-base-engine-3.17.0.jar:3.17.0\]
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:158) \~\[camel-base-engine-3.17.0.jar:3.17.0\]
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBodyAndHeaders(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:326) \~\[camel-base-engine-3.17.0.jar:3.17.0\]
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultProducerTemplate.requestBodyAndHeaders(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:383) \~\[camel-base-engine-3.17.0.jar:3.17.0\]\```

tried using different parameters but no help

The question has nothing to do with Spring for Apache Kafka. Please, be careful when you chose tags for your questions.
